# Max Pixel Value Error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, sentinel, sentinel-5p

I've written below code in Google Earth Engine for carbon monthly product from sentinel-5 but when I click on the run button for save in Google drive, it shows error. How can I solve this problem?

Invalid value at 'max_pixels.value' (TYPE_INT64), "10000000000000000000"

[image]

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fdfa4d5b14c4b64d84da667eba7c2631

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);


var carbon = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2018-11-22','2019-12-28')
.select('CO_column_number_density')
.map(function(img){

  var thr = img.lt(10)
  var mask = img.updateMask(thr);

  return mask.clip(table)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});


var monthly_map = function(collection, start, count, interval, units){

  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0,ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var original_date = ee.Date(start);
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){

    var start_date = original_date.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i),units);
    var end_date = original_date.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)),units);

    return collection.filterDate(start_date,end_date).median()
    .set('system:time_start',start_date.millis())
    .set('system:time_end',end_date.millis());}))}



var carbon_product = monthly_map(carbon,'2018-11-22',12,1,'month');

print(carbon_product)

var carbon_stack = carbon_product.toBands();

print(carbon_stack);


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: carbon_stack,
  description: 'carbon',
  scale: 1000,
  region: table,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  maxPixels: 1e19
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, I've found that the maximum value allowed for the `maxPixels` parameter is `1e13`. Try using it instead of `1e19`.

Comment: I've changed it but it didn't work and mentioned error displayed again.

Comment: It worked for me: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d66d27c9cb90ab0274a42afaee5d1d31

Comment: You are right. thnaks.